# Which iOS app will let me paste an image?

Tags: ios, ipad, copy-paste

**TL;DR; Version:**
I'm looking for an app (preferably free) that will allow me to past an image from the clipboard and save it either to my photo library or to an online service.

**Long Version:**
Several months ago I had some photos stored in my Dropbox which accidentically got deleted without my knowing.  I recently realized the photos were gone and that I had no backups of the photos.  The other day I was in the Dropbox app on my iPad in an area which did not have Internet access.  I noticed that Dropbox had in its cache a bunch of the photos I had lost.  However, Dropbox will not allow me to import the photos into the photo libary or print them or share them; all of these actions return with the error "Unable to Connect to Dropbox - There may be a problem with your iPad's Internet connection."  I can't enable the internet connection because that would sync my Dropbox and loose the photos.  The "Copy Image to Clipboard" action does work, however I can't find any app that will let me paste the image and save it.

I have tried using Evernote, and I can paste the image, but the size limit for notes prevents me from syncing the note.  I've tried GMail and I can paste the image but when I send the message the received e-mail does not have the image attached or included in any way.

Is there an app out there that will let me paste an image and either save it to the photo library or sync with an online service?

Comment: You can't just save the image to the Photos-app and transfer it to your computer that way?

Comment: Or access your Dropbox via www.dropbox.com and undelete the files?

Comment: @Emil, no Dropbox responds with "Unable to Connect to Dropbox - There may be a problem with your iPad's Internet connection."

Comment: But you are able to copy it? This is so weird.

Comment: @patrix, no Dropbox only allows you to undelete your files for 30 days on free accounts.  It has been more than 30 days since the files were deleted.

Comment: Open the photo and take a screenshot. Limited to screen resolution of course, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're able to copy the image, open up the Messages-app, open a new message to your own iMessage-address, and paste, then send. You should be able to save the image to the camera roll from there.

On newer iOS like 10 and higher, the ubiquitous share sheet function lets you move documents around so much easier, that third party apps aren't needed for this basic function anymore.

Comment: How do you save the image from within iMessage?  I can't find anything except "Copy".

Comment: Single-tap the image (either the sent-message or the recieved) – that will display the image in full screen. There you can see a familiar "Share"-icon, click it and click the "Save to Camera Roll"-button :)

Comment: Did it work @heavyd?

Comment: The images in the conversation also get grouped, under the info button, the "Images" tab at the bottom of "Details".

Answer (score 1):

If you can still open them in Dropbox, why not just take a screenshot of each? You may loose some resolution but at least you can save a version of the photo.

Dropbox most probably only cached a preview version of the picture anyway, that's why pasting etc. doesn't work (where the full version would be fetched).

Answer (score 1):

The newer version of Notes supports paste of photos. (I've done this in iOS 10 and later).

Answer (score 0):

Snapseed has a paste option and then save to photo library.

Comment: In this case, a one liner seems sufficient. I hope you don't expect the answer to include a link to the documentation that says "how to paste a photo" and "how to save a photo to the Photo Library". I doubt Apple provides that for any of its first-party apps.

Comment: @benc notes supports this